# Build my application for a previous Windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

#### Background

I'm writing a `C++` app using `VS2015` on `WIN 7`. This app will run on all windows OS greater than equal to `XP`.

Through out my code, I use lots of WINAPI calls.

I wish to prevent, at compile time, the usage of API that are not defined in win `XP`.

#### Motivation

At some point, I used function [RegDeleteKeyEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847(v=vs.85).aspx) without noticing that this API is NOT available in win `XP`

#### Solution

So, I follow this post: [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx) and declared this:

```
#include <winsdkver.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0501         
#define WINVER              0x0501
```

in file `targetver.h`

I was hoping that after this fix, when I compile my project that contains usage of `RegDeleteKeyEx function`, I will get compilation error.
But I didn't.

#### QA

I tried looking for other, [new WINAPI in `vista`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383874(VS.85).aspx), and just added a call to [GetTickCount64 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx). when compiling, I got this:

```
error C3861: 'GetTickCount64': identifier not found
```

which confirmed my solution.

#### Question

I've noticed that for [RegDeleteKeyEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847(v=vs.85).aspx), the `Minimum supported client` is `Windows Vista, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition`

However, my app will run in XP 32 as well.

**How may I enforce compilation error in such use case?**

Comment: You were unlucky.  Unfortunately it *is* available on some SKUs (XP x64, Win2003SP1).  And dates back to the Longhorn troubles, SDK additions were buggy back then.  Using `#undef RegDeleteKeyEx` is the only half-decent workaround to get a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I can see in "winreg.h", there is no conditional compilation of `RegDeleteKeyEx` (other than `RegDeleteKey`). So there is no (easy) way to trigger compilation error in this case.

The only option (for the regular statical DLL loading) would be to create your own wrapper over winreg.h (or windows.h) which would handle the version check (and e.g. `#undef RegDeleteKeyEx` in the corresponding cases).

---

Sometimes this kind of stuff is also solved using dynamic DLL loading (`LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAdress`) where you can check the presence of the particular function on the current version of Windows, where the application runs (so you could for example create a `RegDeleteKey` wrapper which would call `RegDeleteKeyEx` on the windows versions which support it and `RegDeleteKey` if run under versions which don't). The check of the feature presence is then done at runtime, so the program can run on any version of system and still use the newest features on the versions which support them (and doesn't have DLL "unresolved import" loading issues on the lower versions which do not support the feature).

Comment: The dynamic load would be best handled using [Delay Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) so the code can continue to link to `RegDeleteKeyEx()` statically, and then you can utilize a `dliFailGetProc` failure hook to substitute an alternative function on machines where `RegDeleteKeyEx()` is missing.  This way, the code can safely call `RegDeleteKeyEx()` regardless of OS version, and it will either call the native function or the custom function as needed.